# How to redirect the python console output when executed with a os.system command to a QTextBox?

Tags: python, windows, perl, pyqt

I want to execute the perl file using QProcess command in python. But it's not working when i try out with QProcess.start command but executes when i use os.system command. 
How to execute the perl file using QProcess in python and how to redirect the executed output print to a QTextBox?
Here is the piece of code i tried:

here it's not executing the perl file...

```
os.chdir('E:\Jayakanth\python_proj\code\py_files\H264_perl_script')
qprocess = QtCore.QProcess()
qprocess.start('example.pl')
qprocess.waitForFinished(-1)
msg = str(qprocess.readAll())
self.textbrowser.append(msg)
```

but it works like this:

```
import os
os.system('example.pl')
```

or how to redirect the os.system executed python console output to a Qtextbox?

Comment: Well, does qprocess.start offer any return values, error messages, or throw any exceptions?

Comment: Thanks for your support Mr.Len Jaffe
I could solve the above issue following way:
  qprocess.start('E:/path/to/perl.exe', 'example.pl')
But the way we specify the path should be noticed.
And here am stuck with one more issue.
That is i want to run the same in a loop continuously if a QCheckbox is clicked and i have to stop the loop when a QPushbutton is clicked
Please help me with this

Comment: QT is just one of the many things, of which I have no experience. Neither could I find online, a "good" tutorial or reference for QProcess, although if you were to search for QProcess on SO, you'd find several simlar questions and answers that might help you.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Len
Is there a way to call a perl script in python otherthan using the os.system function
If it is possible, please let me know how to do it
Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you appear to be on windows, you might have to provide the full path to the Perl executable in the string passed to os.system()

> os.system('E:\path\to\perl.exe example.pl');

That's my guess.

Comment: It was working with os.system even if i don't give the full path to the perl executable but i couldn't execute with the QProcess.
Any idea on how to execute the same with the QProcess